# Keras Many-to-one predicting the entire sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a keras model that is trained on a sequence of data with a single label. I'm assuming a categorically encoded feature which passes through an embedding layer before a GRU layer.

```
samples, timesteps, features = 2000, 10, 1
inputs_1 = np.random.randint(1, 50, [samples, timesteps, features]).astype(np.float32)
labels = np.random.randint(0, 2, [samples, 1])

# Input
input_ = Input(shape=(None,))


# Embeddings
emb = Embedding(input_dim=int(50),
                            output_dim=20,
                            input_length=(None,),
                            mask_zero=False,
                            name="cat_feat_0" + "_emb")(input_)


gru = GRU(32,
          activation="tanh",
          dropout=0,
          recurrent_dropout=0,
          go_backwards=False,
          return_sequences=False,
          name="gru_cat")(emb)

y = Dense(10, activation = "tanh")(gru)
y = Dropout(0.4)(y)
y = Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid")(y)

model = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=y)
model.compile(loss=BCE_Last_Event,
                          optimizer=Adam(beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999),
                          metrics=["accuracy"])

model.predict(inputs_1).shape
```

When I predict my data, the output shape is `(2000,1)` given that it predicts a single label for the sequence. Would it be possible to output the scores for every event in the sequence such that the model returns predictions of shape `(2000, 10, 1)`?

I know I can return the sequence in the GRU layer which will be propagated. However, I still only have a single label so the loss function would be erroneous. My current thinking is either:

- Create a new model which returns the sequences using the same weights as the trained model
- Wrap the model in a TimeDistributed layer such that it predicts every event in the sequence.

I am concerned that the second solution will be error-prone as it will only take as input a single event throughout the entire length of the sequence, rather than the entire sequence for its prediction. Is this thinking correct?

What are the best solutions?